# pandas.DataFrame.rename not changing the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I was working on a data frame called energy_df which contains indices such as "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", I wish to change this to "Bolivia " in the indices effectively removing the part in the parentheses

```
 for country in energy_df.index:
    paren_in=country.find('(')
    if paren_in!=-1:
        internal=country[:paren_in]
        energy_df.rename(index={country:internal})
```

however this does not seem to work. What is the reason? How can I fix this?

Sample I/O: If the DataFrame is something like

Bolivia (Plurinational State of) | 1 | 2 | abc

the output should be

Bolivia  | 1 | 2 | abc

Comment: Please share a sample input and expected output of your dataframe. That makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the [`pd.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) argument `inplace=true` to modify the dataframe in place:

```py
energy_df.rename(index={country: internal}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was a quick fix!

Comment: @Michael Delgado yes I will do that once the required time elapses.

Comment: Ahh got it :) that _was_ a quick fix!

Answer (score 0):

Also add the error parameter to make sure it raises error if the index is not found.

energy_df.rename(index={country: internal}, inplace=True, errors = 'raise')